# Problem in understanding path dependence of friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction, integration

I was trying to solve this question, and I thought I did until I saw the solution. This is a standard problem in classical mechanics.

> *A ball of mass $m$ is slowly pulled along an irregular rough surface from A to B slowly. Find work done by external force*

My solution: This is how I interpreted the problem. pulling it slowly means no acceleration. Then I applied the Work energy theorem. $W_F+W_g+W_N+W_f=0$ since the final and initial kinetic energy is zero. Work done by normal force is also zero because displacement is always perpendicular to the surface. and Since gravity is a conservative force it is path-independent. $mgH+W_f+W_F=0$ and $W_f=$$-\int_0^L \mu mg\cos\theta \,dx$ where $\theta$ is a variable dependent on x. So the answer would be $W_F=mg(\mu\int_0^L \mu mg\cos\theta \,dx+H)$ But apparently the solution is $mg(\mu L+H)$ But according to my equation, this is only true if the path is straight and not for any arbitrary curve. Where am I going wrong someone help.

[image]

Comment: Note that the $\text{d}x$ in your integral should actually be $\text{d}s,$ the increment of arclength.

Comment: yeah, I understand now my mistake. But like doesn't this make friction like a conservative force, I mean that for any path we can apply the same logic and friction becomes a conservative force.

Comment: The frictional work $dW=mg\mu \frac{dx}{ds}ds$where ds is differential distance measured along the curved arc and x is horizontal distance.  The total horizontal distance is L.